# What is the equivalent for this? SFML

Tags: c++, version, sfml

```
if(Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(key))
```

This was from SFML 1.6, I believe, and I'm using SFML 2.1.
`key` is an integer, and `Window` is the name of a window.
I get an error saying: `error: sf::RenderWindow has no member named 'GetInput'`.
What do I replace it with?
This is my code:

```
bool inputmanager::keydown(sf::RenderWindow &Window, int key){
    if(Window.GetInput().IsKeyDown(key)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Edit: I need key is ***down***, not key is ***pressed***, like hold down a key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sf::Input::isKeyDown(key)) {
    // ... 
}
```

Where `key` can be converted to a representable value of [`sf::Keyboard::Key`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Keyboard.php).

Comment: What about key is down?

Comment: error: 'isKeyDown' is not a member of 'sf::Keyboard'

Comment: @user3882772 Not `KeyIsDown`, it's [*`isKeyDown`*](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/1.6/classsf_1_1Input.php#a5312ed524e1f2837aa4597978553876a).

Comment: Really sorry, that's what I meant.

Comment: The function is `isKeyPressed`.

Comment: @user3882772 Okay, use `sf::Input::isKeyDown` (note the `Input` instead of `Keyboard`, my fault) :)

Comment: @user3882772: There's no difference.

Comment: OK, it said it needs to be declared. How to?

Comment: @hyil: `sf::Input` is not in SFML 2.1.

Comment: @user3882772: `#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>`. It's also brought in by `<SFML/Window.hpp>`

Answer (score 2):

http://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.0/window-inputs.php

You should be able to look these up first!

SFML now has a class to handle the Keyboard input under sf::Keyboard.

Comment: I did, and didn't find anything. By the way, I'm using 2.1.